# Is there a way to loop my code back/a function if a response is received? and also use the sleep

Tags: python, json, function, loops, python-requests

I want to make a script where there are a few functions, the first is the `add_cart` which by name attempts to add an item to cart using proper cookies/headers because I can get a response which I get that `["error"]` to print the log which will say `retrying cart` but the script suddenly stops even if I put the `add_cart()` function on the bottom but I also want to use the datetime module to `time.sleep(2)` before running the `add_cart()` function so confused how I could get this all up and running, I attached images below with my code it currently gets a response because it's printing in the terminal but I want to find out what I said above. Thanks!

Image (All code with headers, cookies, and payload minimized)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVwRD.png

Please inform if something is wrong or any way I can fix my formatting? Again all headers, cookies, payload, requests url and responses is right trying to fix my other errors though

this is the full code since the bot said add it:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os



cookies = {

}

headers = {

}

atcPayload = {

}



def add_cart(cookies, headers, atcPayload):
    response = requests.post('apiurl', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=atcPayload)

    data = response.json()

    print("adding")

    if data["error"] == 'true':
        print("retrying cart")

#(cookies/stuff hidden because it's a private project but that isn't the issue anyways)

Seems to be another issue where it won't run now in the visual studio code terminal either :(
```

Comment: Hi Steve, so you want a main loop where you call your function then wait 2 seconds and call again?

Comment: I want it to ONLY loop if the response is received from the post request in ```add_cart``` which works to print the status message for me currently ```retrying cart``` but i want it to loop that function but sleep 2 seconds before ONLY if that response is received

Comment: the ```if data["error"] == 'true':``` is checking if the response has the error listed in the json as true which I want then to print the retrying cart status, sleep 2 seconds, then re run the code and keep looping until another is received where it will run a different one called ```auth_order``` but assuming I get the first one working I could figure out the 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you problem correctly, you would like to implement a loop, where you call your function, then wait 2 seconds, and do it indefinetly.

*edit

I hope I get it right now :)

Modified the code based on your comments, now it wait until "ok" returns from your function.

```
import time
import sys
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

Start_Time = datetime.now()
# Your function
def add_cart():
    # This is for make some timing response
    global Start_Time    
    Return_Value = "retry cart"

    Current_Time = datetime.now()
    # Just print out the current time
    print(Current_Time)
    
    # Get 10 second delay on status change
    if Current_Time>(Start_Time+timedelta(seconds=10)):
        Return_Value = "ok"

    return Return_Value
    
# The main function
def main():
    # For the response from the function    
    Response = None
    # This will make an infinite loop
    while True:
        # Call your function, it will return "rety cart" until 10 seconds not pass, then it returns "ok"
        Response = add_cart()
        print(Response)

        # Wait 2 second
        time.sleep(2)
        # Check the response and break out from the while loop
        if ("ok" == Response):
            break
        

# This will run if you run your file, and not run if you import it (for later use)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Run the main function defined above
        main()
    # If you want to interrupt the script press CTRL+c and the below part will catch it
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: No! I want it to only loop if the response is recieved from the initial ```add_cart``` request which works to print the status message saying ```retry cart``` but I want it to also loop based on that status message

Comment: the ```if data["error"] == 'true':``` is checking if the response has the error listed in the json as true which I want then to print the retrying cart status, sleep 2 seconds, then re run the code and keep looping until another is received where it will run a different one called ```auth_order``` but assuming I get the first one working I could figure out the 2nd

Comment: Confused at this, it's supposed to make a post request with a payload to a url then check the response if the response has the error true re run the code? is this it or

Comment: i just used a dummy or mock function in the code, if you use your function and change the return values to what you need, it can do it, it will run until your function not return a value which breaks the while loop

Comment: Ok let me try and rephrase, so the ```add_cart``` response has either a ```{"error":"true",``` or ```{"error":"false",``` in the response, I want it to retry the ```add_cart``` function after 2 seconds ONLY if   ```if atcResponse["error"] == 'true':``` which atcResponse is the returned json value from the previous POST request in the ```add_cart``` function.

So in hindsight, I only want it to loop after 2 seconds if the proper response is received I can have it print ```retrying cart``` which is based off the  ``` {"error":"true",``` response